# Equivalent to Lead and Lag in order to get the number of previous purchases

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata. I have the following table and need the following result table:

[image: Given Table and Result Table]

Result table is continuation of the 2 tables and i have not mentioned the remaining columns for the ProdType : Rugby. But there would be 5 more columns for Rugby that is understandable.

I am able to write the following query which generates only the current and previous revenues for each ProdType. I am not sure how i would proceed it to write it for different Time Spans of Last3Months, Last1Year and LifeTime.

My query is:

```
select ORDERNO, ORDERTIME,PRODNAME, PRODTYPE,

(CASE WHEN PRODTYPE = 'CRICKET' then REVENUE ELSE 0 END) as CRICKET_CURRREV,
MIN(CRICKET_CURRREV) OVER (ORDER BY CRICKET_CURRREV ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS CRICKET_PREVREV,

(CASE WHEN PRODTYPE = 'SOCCER' then REVENUE ELSE 0 END) as SOCCER_CURRREV,
MIN(SOCCER_CURRREV) OVER (ORDER BY SOCCER_CURRREV ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS SOCCER_PREVREV,

(CASE WHEN PRODTYPE = 'RUGBY' then REVENUE ELSE 0 END) as RUGBY_CURRREV,
MIN(RUGBY_CURRREV) OVER (ORDER BY RUGBY_CURRREV ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS RUGBY_PREVREV

FROM GIVEN TABLE WHERE USERID='123'
ORDER BY ORDERTIME;
```

So in the result table, i need the revenue for every Product Type before that Particular order in different time spans. For example, the 3rd record is CricBall which is Cricket. Hence my CricketPrevRev is 44.24 (First Cricket Product revenue) and i am able to get that. But if you see the same record, the field of Cricket_Last1Year also should have 44.24 because CricBall was ordered on 31Oct2011, so within a Year before this product was ordered, CricBat was ordered i.e 12Nov2010. So the revenue of CricBat should be reflected in 3rd record.
I hope the example makes it clear.
The same should hold true for every product. The lifetime columns for product should be the total revenue generated before that particular product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your original LAG/LEAD code? It's probably using RANGE which is not supported in Teradata and emulating it is really hard. What's the actual number of rows you're going to process?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use case statements to derive your relative buckets, like `Last3Months`.

Comment: Hi, this is my original code. I just saw the concept of lead/lag in oracle and saw some post on teradata forums and wrote the above query. I think i am going to process around 40,000,000 rows

Comment: Hi dnoeth, is there a way we can get the timespan columns using teradata query? I am completely unaware of the same.

Comment: The timespans need RANGE which is not supported, only *prevRev* and *LifeTime* is easy (at least in TD14.10), e.g.: `CASE WHEN PRODTYPE = 'CRICKET' THEN LAST_VALUE(CRICKET_CURRREV IGNORE NULLS ) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY ORDERTIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) end AS CRICKET_PREVREV,

CASE WHEN PRODTYPE = 'CRICKET' THEN SUM(CRICKET_CURRREV ) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY ORDERTIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) end AS CRICKET_LifeTime`. How many rows per `USERID` exist in average/maximum and how often do you need to run this query?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, there are 3 to 4 rows per userid. And i just need to join the result table with the final query and it would be run may be not that often. Just for analytic purposes i need to run it and capture the results.

Comment: Hi dnoeth, the changes work for the lifetime values, but it does not work for the previous values. For example, in the 3rd record, i  donot get the revenue of 44.24 in the column of cricket_prevrev. I get it as 0. Whereas the query i mentioned, it works for the previous. Is that correct?